# Resize some images with mogrify to another directory to same filename

Tags: regex, bash, imagemagick, mogrify

These are files in my directory:

```
01.png  01_v2.png  02.png  02_v2.png
```

I would like to:

1. take just `01_v2.png` and `02_v2.png`
2. resize it to `750x1334`
3. place it in parent directory `04_4,7`
4. but with same filename `01_v2.png` and `02_v2.png`

I have come to this command:

```
mogrify *_*.png -resize 750x1334 ../04_4,7/*.png
```

*This command is valid for points 1-3, but not for point 4.*

It is renaming `01_v2.png` to `01.png` and `02_v2.png` to `02.png`, but I want the output filename to be the same as the input filename.

Answer (score 1):

that looks more like a shell question than imagemagick, doesn't it?

assuming a bash like shell, you can do the following:

```
for f in 01_v2.png 02_v2.png; do
    convert "$f" -resize 750x1334 "../04_4,7/$f"
done
```

Comment: I found that this work `convert *_*.png -resize 750x1334 -set filename:f '%t' ../04_4,7/'%[filename:f].png'`. I do not know is it possible with mogrify.

Comment: sorry, I didn't remember the difference between mogrify and convert. The imagemagick site says: "mogrify is similiar to convert except that the original image file is overwritten (unless you change the file suffix with the -format option) with any changes you request. " Therefore, you can use `convert` in your case...

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if you're using bash for this, although if you are the `find` command should work:

```
find . -iregex '^.*_v.\.png' -exec mogrify -path ../04_4,7/ -resize 750x1334 {} \;
```

Searches for any file file with `(2 chars)_(letter "v")(1 char).png` then performs the mogrify command into the directory following `-path` at the specified dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is like this:

```
mogrify  -path ../04_4,7  -resize 750x1334  *v2.png
```

**Note:**

`-path` sets the output directory

`*v2.png` selects the input files